# How to split document using page break in java Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am setting the application who index the document and tells on which page the word appeared and how many times so I need to split document using page break. I tried some code but it does not work

```
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = xdoc.getParagraphs();
int pageCount = 1;
for (XWPFParagraph par :paragraphs) {
    if (par.getParagraphText().contains("\f")) {
        ++pageCount;
    }
}
System.out.println(pageCount);
```

Comment: List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = xdoc.getParagraphs();
int pageCount = 1;
for (XWPFParagraph par :paragraphs) {
    if (par.getParagraphText().contains("\f")) {
        ++pageCount;
    }
   // xdoc.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().get
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println(pageCount);

Comment: Have you tried [XWPFParagraph.isPageBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#isPageBreak--)? `if (par.isPageBreak()) ++pageCount;`. But of course this works only if there explicit page breaks are set. Automatic page breaks are not detectable without rendering the document and `apache poi` is not rendering the document.

Comment: i tried but it is not detecting page break

Comment: Then this is not an explicit set page break in document. As said, automatic page breaks are not detectable without rendering the document and `apache poi` is not rendering the document.